# Relative paths and includes

Tags: php, path, relative-path

So I have some php files that I'm trying to include with no luck.

I have the root directory, and off that I have a directory called aboutus.  In the aboutus directory, I'm trying to include a css file from the root.  So I use this code:

```
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/meta-head.php";
```

The include works fine, but in the meta-head.php there are some calls to files, one of which is:

```
    <script src="_assets/js/navbar.js"></script>
```

The problem is that it's trying to access this from root/aboutus/_assets/js/navbar.js (which doesn't exist), when I want it to acccess it at root/_assets/js/navbar.js.

What am I doing wrong so that it won't access the file relative to the root?

Thank you!

Comment: Use `/root/_assets/js/navbar.js` as the "src" attribute of your script, assuming `root` is the root of your publicly accessible website.

Answer (score 0):

use absolute path or use this:

```
<script src="/_assets/js/navbar.js"></script>
```